# Firefox disappears after reboot

Tags: unity, firefox

I set my Uncle up with Ubuntu while I was doing some work on his website in France and he's recently emailed me with a troubling issue.

It appears that, when he reboots his computer, Firefox disappears from the side-bar and, despite being in the Unity menu system, he is unable to launch it from there either - until he un-installs and re-installs Firefox.

Comment: go to terminal > firefox > and lock it on the launcher

Comment: He can search for it in the hub, right? If so, he can open it using the hub and once it is open he rightclicks the firefox icon in the sidebar (which is not called a sidebar, but a launcher or so I think) and chooses to Lock it to the launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the uncle here. I am new to Ubuntu so forgive me but though I do know what you mean by the launcher I don't know what you mean by 'hub'.
When I search for 'Firefox' in the Dash-Board I get the Icon but it won't initiate it.
I have to remove and then re-install (using the software centre) to get it working but then on reboot I am back to square one.
I'm on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I used terminal to initiate Firefox as suggested by Qasim and then locked onto launcher (BTW this had not been an option before) and after rebooting it has locked onto the launcher so thanks for your help, problem solved.

Comment: Good to know ...you have solved the problem ..+1